# Intersection of 2-d numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a way to get the intersection between two 2-dimensional `numpy.array` of shape `(n_1, m)` and `(n_2, m)`. Note that `n_1` and `n_2` can differ but m is the same for both arrays. Here are two minimal examples with the expected results:

```
import numpy as np

array1a = np.array([[2], [2], [5], [1]])
array1b = np.array([[5], [2]])

array_intersect(array1a, array1b)
##  array([[2],
##         [5]])


array2a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 3], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1]])
array2b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 4], [3, 3]])

array_intersect(array2a, array2b)
##  array([[2, 1],
##         [3, 3]])
```

If someone have a clue on how I should implement the `array_intersect` function, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand, how exactly you define the intersection. Is it a matrix consisting of all the rows of the second matrix present in the first one? Or vice versa?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear! I just want that any row that exist in the two arrays to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using sets?

```
import numpy as np

array2a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 3], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1]])
array2b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 4], [3, 3]])


a = set((tuple(i) for i in array2a))
b = set((tuple(i) for i in array2b))

a.intersection(b) # {(2, 1), (3, 3)}
```

Comment: This is my favorite one since it's easier to read. I implemented it in a function where I return `np.array(list(a.intersection(b)))` since I want the output to be a `numpy.array`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This may be acceptable in terms of performance for small arrays; but note that this foregoes numpy-like performance, and involves the creation of many seperate python objects with their associated overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a set of tuples from the first array and test each line of the second array. Or vice versa.

```
def array_intersect(a, b):
    s = {tuple(x) for x in a}
    return np.unique([x for x in b if tuple(x) in s], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to harness the broadcasting feature

```
import numpy as np

array2a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 3], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1]])
array2b = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 4], [3, 3]])

test = array2a[:, None] == array2b
print(array2b[np.all(test.mean(0) > 0, axis = 1)]) # [[2 1]
                                                   # [3 3]]
```

but this is less readable imo. [edit]: or use the unique and set combination. In short, there are many options!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do without any loops or list comprehensions, assuming you have `scipy` installed (I haven't tested for speed):

```
In [31]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

In [32]: np.unique(array1a[np.where(cdist(array1a, array1b) == 0)[0]], axis=0)
Out[32]: 
array([[2],
       [5]])

In [33]: np.unique(array2a[np.where(cdist(array2a, array2b) == 0)[0]], axis=0)
Out[33]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The numpy-indexed [package](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) (disclaimer: I am its author) was created with the exact purpose of providing such functionality in an expressive and efficient manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.intersect(a, b)
```

Note that the implementation is fully vectorized; that is no loops over the arrays in python.

Comment: gives me the module 'numpy_indexed' has no attribute 'intersect' error

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = np.arange(20000).reshape(-1,2)
arr2 = arr1.copy()
np.random.shuffle(arr2)
print(len(arr1)) #10000
```

```
%%timeit
res= np.array([x
   for x in set(tuple(x) for x in arr1) & set(tuple(x) for x in arr2)
])
```

```
83.7 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```